# How to complete the diagram so that it becomes commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider the following diagram of left $R$-modules ($R$ is a ring with identity $1_R$) and $R$-linear maps with exact lines:

[image]

where $M$ is free. How do define $R$-lineas maps $M\longrightarrow M^\prime$ and $L\longrightarrow L^\prime$ turning the diagram commutative?

I'm a bit lost as to how the fact $M$ is free will come into play.

Thanks.

Comment: To get the map from $M$ to $M'$ you just need to use that $M$ is projective.

Comment: And to get the map from $L$ to $L'$ afterwards, you need the exactness of the sequences. The map $L\to M \to M' \to N'$ is zero, hence the map $L\to M \to M'$ factors over the kernel of $M' \to N'$, which is $L'$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I haven't seen projective modules yet so I guess I can't use it, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is not free, the diagram may not be completed as wished, consider the diagram of $\mathbf Z$-modules$\def\Z{\mathbf Z}$
$$ 
\begin{matrix} 0 & \def\To{\longrightarrow}\To &  0 & \To & \Z/(2) & \To & \Z/(2) & \To & 0 \\
   && && && \downarrow {\rm id}&& \\
 0 & \To & \Z & \stackrel{\cdot 2}\To & \Z & \To & \Z/(2) & \To & 0 
\end{matrix}
$$
The only homomorphism $\Z/(2) \to \Z$ does not make the diagram commutative. But if $M$ is free, you can start by defining $M \to M'$ on a free generating set.